# How do I plot a graph by date give a count of another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm not sure how to ask this kind of question but here's the DataFrame I have

```
Date, ID, Count, Is_Correct
2023-06-01, 1, 12, True
2023-06-01, 1, 1, False
2023-06-02, 2, 15, True
2023-06-02, 2, 10, True
2023-06-02, 2, 1, False
```

What I want is a graph to show a percentage of `False`

For example after processing then I'm expecting the result to be something like this so I can plot a graph to show the percentage of `False`

```
2023-06-01, True, 12
2023-06-01, False, 1
2023-06-02, True, 25
2023-06-02, False, 1
```

Ultimately, I just want to show the percentage of `False` per day.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape your dataframe with:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Is_Correct'])['Count'].sum()
out = df1.unstack().eval('Pct = `False` / `True`')
```

Output:

```
>>> df1.reset_index()
         Date Is_Correct  Count
0  2023-06-01      False      1
1  2023-06-01       True     12
2  2023-06-02      False      1
3  2023-06-02       True     25


>>> out.reset_index()[['Date', 'Pct']].rename_axis(columns=None)
         Date       Pct
0  2023-06-01  0.083333
1  2023-06-02  0.040000
```